# IE8 rendering on mousemove or scroll

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Strange issue in IE8, in all other browsers its working fine
When page is loaded it shows content like this
[image]

After I move my mouse or scroll page, its fixed like this (On all other browser its looking always like this)
[image]

I am displaying the tabular data purely using div and css (no tables) What could be the possible cause of such rendering issues in IE8?

Comment: I learned from past experiences that if ie8 is doing something strange, you should first of all validate your code on http://validator.w3.org/ . If you already did, I think we will need access to the code to figure this out.

Comment: Maybe if you can post your code here we will understand the problem more. But if it is build with div's. Maybe IE 8 renders a different padding value Or clearing each div will help.